# Горизонтальный скролл колесиком

Tags: html, css, прокрутка

Помогите пожалуйста сделать горизонтальный скролл колесиком мышки, чтобы при наведении мышкой на блок, где присутствует скролл по горизонтали - становился активным, и можно было бы скроллить чисто колесиком мыши, хотелось бы чисто на css, если такое вообще возможно, так как с js не дружу еще, и без поворотов блока, заранее огромное спасибо!

Comment: Или через JS, или через повороты контейнера и блоков. По-другому никак.

Comment: А если через js делать, сложно все? Если не знать этот язык программирования)

Comment: нет, не сложно даже для начинающего. В сети много примеров, это стандартные уроки JS.